# my android app crashes after i made some changes in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I made some changes for the action bar and then the app is not working anymore.

It's says that

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.getDecorView()' on a
>   null object reference

I don't know what to do.

Here is the logcat log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.george.photoeditor/com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.getDecorView()' on a null object reference                                                                  
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:165)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.getDecorView()' on a null object reference
  at android.app.Activity.initWindowDecorActionBar(Activity.java:2162)
  at android.app.Activity.getActionBar(Activity.java:2122)
  at com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:42)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2347)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:165) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

This is styles.xml code where I made the changes:

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:action">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: share your colors.xml, your styles.xml are with the changes or without?

Comment: You may see that logcat says the error is inside of MainActivity line 42. Put codes for MainActivity and color.xml

Comment: Do you have a custom `View` element in your xml file?

Comment: here is colors.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
</resources>

Comment: Guys,thank you for your help. Seriously this thing made me really mad. I just changed the public class MainActivity extends Activity to public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity. I'm new to this android programming. I searched a lot for changing the action bar ,but i didn't find clear tutorials. if you know where I should look,help me :) Thank you again,for your time.